# SSRS Chart. How to plot line to decrease totals by date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a chart in SSRS that has dollar totals by date.  I would like a line chart that starts with the total dollars and then decreases the total by date until it gets to zero.  How can I do that?

Comment: You should probably go [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239351.aspx) if you need to know how to make a chart, the way your question is worded it seems like you want a full tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Line Chart

In "Chart Data" add the following expression to the "Values" part  (with the green plus sign): "=RunningValue(Fields!colVal.Value,Sum,"DataSet1")" where colVal is the field that you want to sum up, and "DataSet1" is the scope

Then right click on the horizontal axis -> Properties -> Side Margin Disabled + Scale Options = Reverse Direction

Hope this helps!